# How do I convert a string to a dictionary in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var str = "1:6,5,2,2:3";
```

I want to convert this `str` into a js dictionary such that:

```
var dict = {1:"6,5,2",
            2:"3"};
```

so that I can fetch the values by their respective key index. How do I convert it?

I had tried this code to store the splitted values into an array:

```js
var pages = "1:6,5,2,2:3";
var numbers = [];
if (pages.includes(',')) {
  page_nos = pages.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < page_nos.length; i++) {
    if (page_nos[i].includes(':')) {
      var n = page_nos[i].split(':');
      numbers.push(n[1]);
    } else {
      numbers.push(page_nos[i]);
    }
  }
} else {
  page_nos = pages.split(':');
  numbers.push(page_nos[1])
};

console.log('numbers: ', numbers);
```

But it's incorrect, as without `dictionary` it's impossible to know what value belongs to which index

Comment: Where is that string coming from? Might be easier to change its source. For example to JSON.

Comment: The `dict` variable listed in the question is termed an `"Object"` in javascript. It may be loosely considered equivalent to a python dict insofar as both hold key-value pairs.

Comment: Second the suggestion by @JavaScript. One will need to determine which `","` is separating numbers within a string & which marks end of a string and the "key" of the next key-value pair.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How is the string created? If the creation of the string is in your control, you need to change it to a valid JSON string. Instead of using regex to parse the string to an object

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot make your input string a proper JSON or another easily parsable format in the first place, this answers your question:

```js
const str = "1:6,5,2,2:3";

const obj = str.split(/,(?=\d+:)/).reduce((accu, part) => {
  const [k, v] = part.split(':', 2);
  accu[k] = v;
  return accu;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Cut the string at all commas that are followed by digits and a colon. Each part has a key in front of a colon and a value after it, which should be stuffed in an object in this format.

Comment: Nice solution, I noticed you have an unnecessary parenthesis wrapping your reduce callback, however.

Comment: @Undo You're right; I removed them.

Answer (score 1):

No mutations solution.

```js
const str = "1:6,5,2,2:3";

const dict = str
  .split(/(\d+:.*)(?=\d+:)/g)
  .reduce((t, c) => {
    const [key, value] = c.replace(/,$/, "").split(/:/);
    return { ...t, [key]: value }
  });

  
console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you consider not using regular expression, you might try this as well.
to take out a dict (Object) from that string, this will do.

```js
var pages = "1:6,5,2,2:3";

function stringToObject(str) {
    
  var page_object = {};

  var last_object;

  str.split(",").forEach((item) => {
    if (item.includes(":")) {
      page_object[item.split(":")[0]] = item.split(":")[1];

      last_object = item.split(":")[0];
    } else {
      page_object[last_object] += `,${item}`;
    }
  });
  return page_object;
}

console.log(stringToObject(pages))
```

Answer (score 0):

Presented below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**NOTE:**
In lieu of `var` the code uses either `let` or `const` as applicable.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const pages = "1:6,5,2,2:3";
const resObj = {};
let page_nos, k;
if (pages.includes(',')) {
  page_nos = pages.split(',');
  for (let i = 0; i < page_nos.length; i++) {
    if (page_nos[i].includes(':')) {
      let n = page_nos[i].split(':');
      k = n[0];
      resObj[k] = n[1].toString();
    } else {
      resObj[k] += ", " + page_nos[i].toString();
    }
  }
} else {
  page_nos = pages.split(':');
  resObj[page_nos[0]] = [page_nos[1]]
  numbers.push(page_nos[1])
};

console.log('result object: ', resObj);
```

This code essentially fixes the code given in the question. It is self-explanatory and any specific information required may be added based on questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could take nested splitring for entries and get an object from it.

```js
const
    str = "1:6,5,2,2:3",
    result = Object.fromEntries(str
        .split(/,(?=[^,]*:)/)
        .map(s => s.split(':'))
    );

console.log(result);
```